# PHP show error if inputbox1 > inputbox2

Tags: javascript, php

I designed a php page if current time is greater than end time it show as closed else it show data entry form.
In that form I have several input boxes some get value from database.remain input boxes accept value less than their pair input box.else it show error and focus user to change that field how ... I tried with following code but cannot get expected result... Any solution...

```
<?php 
include("head.php");

?>
<?php
$end = ('04:15:00 PM');
$now=date('H:i:s  A');?>

<?php 
$newdateformat = date("d_m_y");
$ttaerr="";
mysql_select_db($mysql_database,$bd);
$se_sql=mysql_query("select * from $newdateformat where  S_No='$login_sess' ");

$row=mysql_fetch_array($se_sql);
$name=$row['S_Name'];
$address=$row['Address'];
$tamil=  $row['Tamil1'];
$english=$row['English1'];
$maths= $row['Maths1']; ?>

<label> Your Name : <?php echo $login_sess;?> - <?php echo $name;?> - <?php echo $address;?> </label><br />
<?php


if($end > $now){
    echo "Entry 1 Closed :";

}

else
  { 
    ?>  




    <form id='form1' name='form1' method='post' action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>'>'

  <p>
    <label for='tamil1'>Tamil 1 : </label>
    <input name='tamil1' type='text' id='tamil1' value='<?php echo $tamil;?>'  readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled"/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for='tamil2'>Tamil 2 : </label>
    <input name='tamil2' type='text'  id='tamil2' maxlength="3"  required='required'  /> <?php echo $ttaerr;?>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for='tamil1'>English 1 : </label>
    <input type='text' name='english1' id='english1' value='<?php echo $english;?>' readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled"/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for='tamil2'>English 2 : </label>
    <input type='text' name='english2' id='english2'   required='required' maxlength="3" />
</p>
  <p>
    <label for='tamil1'>Maths 1 : </label>
    <input type='text' name='maths1' id='maths1' value='<?php echo $maths;?>' readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for='tamil2'>Maths 2 : </label>
    <input type='text' name='maths2' id='maths2'  required='required' maxlength="3" />
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' />
  </p>

</form>
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
{ if(isset($_POST['tamil1'])&&isset($_POST['tamil2'])&&isset($_POST['english1'])&&isset($_POST['english2'])&&isset($_POST['maths1'])&&($_POST['maths2']))
{
$newta1=$_POST['tamil1'];
$newta2=$_POST['tamil2'];
$newen1=$_POST['english1'];
$newen2=$_POST['english2'];
$newma1=$_POST['maths1'];
$newma2=$_POST['maths2'];

if(($newta1 > $newta2)&&($newen1 > $newen2)&&($newma1 > $newma2))
{
    $sql="UPDATE $newdateformat SET  Time='$now',Tamil2='newta2',English2='$newen2',Maths2='$newma2' WHERE S_NO='$login_sess' and S_Name='$name'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

 if(!$result) 
{
    die ('Error:'.mysql_error().'<br> <a href=""> Back</a>');
}
echo 'Your Record added on :'.$now.'<br> <a href=""> Back</a>';
mysql_close($con);  
    }
else {
    echo("Try Eng...");

}}
    }

        }

        ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is something you want to use JavaScript for and can easily be done wit JQuery.

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Is it possible with php ?

Comment: Hi jeroen Tamil 1 input box get value from database users only allowed to enter value in tamil2 .I want to sho error when they enter value greater than tamil1. Likewise english1 vs english2 maths1 vs maths2.

Comment: It's better to do validation in both jQuery and php, it's ok to do only php, it's not ok to do only jquery. Yes, ofcourse it can be done with php after you receive the post values, check them with current values from your db query and update them (or not) accordingly.

Comment: Ya... Which is I need ,just guide with that db query. How can I do that